# Unable to profile non-responsing JVM application

Tags: eclipse, java-11

We have an IDE based on eclipse. Sometimes the Application goes to not responding state for more than 30 minutes.
During this non-responding state, if I try of profile using JMissionControl or JVisualVM, the profiling fails. JVisualVM does not list the JVM in which the IDE app is running and JMissionControl's flight recording fails to start as well.

When using JStack to take the threaddump, it is failing with the below error:

```
at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.enqueue(Native Method)
at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.execute(VirtualMachineImpl.java:96)
at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.executeCommand(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:309)
at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.getAgentProperties(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:202)
```

Using,
OpenJDK 11.0.16.1
Eclipse IDE Platform: 4.16
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3324]

Any help to find out about why the tool is entering non-responding or why the profiling tools are unable to connect to the app's JVM?

Thanks,
Pal

Comment: `Native Method` means it happens outside of the JVM in native code (in a Windows .dll file, not in Java code). Eclipse 4.16 is more than three years and 12 releases behind. Please upgrade.

Comment: @howlger you mean this happens at the native code of JVM of the profiler right?
Yeah, the plan is underway to upgrade the eclipse, but, we are facing this profilers not working in some of the users from older eclipse as well. I'm wondering what the profiler not to record and fail?

Comment: Yes, the topmost stack trace item is [`sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.enqueue(...)` which is a native method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/3e1b1bf94e7acf9717b837085e61fc05a7765de4/src/jdk.attach/windows/classes/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachineImpl.java#L159C29-L159C29). The C code for Windows can be found [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/3e1b1bf94e7acf9717b837085e61fc05a7765de4/src/jdk.attach/windows/native/libattach/VirtualMachineImpl.c).